# Error instantiating chaincode in Hyperledger Fabric 1.4 over AKS kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, azure-aks

I am trying to instantiate "sacc" chaincode (which comes with fabric samples) in an hyperledger fabric network deployed over kubernetes in AKS. After hours trying different adjustments, I've not been able to finish the task. I'm always getting the error:

> Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not
>   successful, error code 500, msg timeout expired while starting
>   chaincode sacc:0.1 for transaction

Please note that there is no transaccion ID in the error (I've googled some similar cases, but in all of them, there was an ID for the transaction. Not my case, eventhough the error is the same)

The message in the orderer:

> 2019-07-23 12:40:13.649 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN
>   047 Error reading from 10.1.0.45:52550: rpc error: code = Canceled
>   desc = context canceled 2019-07-23 12:40:13.649 UTC [comm.grpc.server]
>   1 -> INFO 048 streaming call completed {"grpc.start_time":
>   "2019-07-23T12:34:13.591Z", "grpc.service": "orderer.AtomicBroadcast",
>   "grpc.method": "Broadcast", "grpc.peer_address": "10.1.0.45:52550",
>   "error": "rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled",
>   "grpc.code": "Canceled", "grpc.call_duration": "6m0.057953469s"}

I am calling for instantiation from inside a cli peer, defining variables CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID, CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE, CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH, CORE_PEER_ADDRESS and ORDERER_CA with appropriate values before issuing the instantiation call:

> peer chaincode instantiate -o  -n sacc -v 0.1 -c
>   '{"Args":["init","hi","1"]}' -C mychannelname --tls 'true' --cafile
>   $ORDERER_CA

- All the peers have declared a dockersocket volume pointing to
  /run/docker.sock
- All the peers have declared the variable CORE_VM_ENDPOINT to unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
- All the orgs were joined to the channel
- All the peers have the chaincode installed

I can't see any further message/error in the cli, nor in the orderer, nor in the peers involved in the channel.

Any ideas on what can be going wrong? Or how could I continue troubleshooting the problem? Is it possible to see logs from the docker container that is being created by the peers? how?

Thanks

Comment: "Is it possible to see logs from the docker container that is being created by the peers? how?" Are they managed by kubernetes ? `kubectl logs pod-name` or `docker logs container-name` don't show anything ?

Comment: Hello, I am having same problem with a 1.13.11 version cluster running in Azure AKS. Did you manage to solve it? Are you sure we should be using docker.sock and not containerd (tcp://docker:2375) ? Thanks for any help.